# Laravel Update is not working tells _method unknown column

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am new to laravel working in a small project. I am having problem with update my table.

My edit field is

```
{{ Form::model($participantedit, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('dota.update', $participantedit->idparticipant))) }}
    <table border="0">
        <input type="text" name="participant_name" value="<?php echo $participantedit['participant_name']; ?>" />
        <li>{{ Form::submit('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}</li>
{{Form::close()}}
```

My Update function is

```
public function update($id){
    $input = Input::all();
    return Participant::where('idparticipant', '=', $id)->update($input);
}
```

I'm getting an error that the column `_method` is unknown.

Comment: I would also recommend to `validate` your input with the [Validator class](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Laravel automatically adds a `_method` field to your form. It does that because HTML forms don't support methods like `PATCH`. So it sends the field `_method` with value `patch` along to support other verbs than just POST and GET.

What you can do is use `Input::except()`. It will return all inputs but remove the specified ones before:

```
$input = Input::except('_method');
```

You probably also need to exclude the CSRF token:

```
$input = Input::except('_method', '_token');
```

Alternatively you can use `Input::only()` which does the opposite:

```
$input = Input::only('foo', 'bar'); // foo and bar are values you actually want
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of PATCH, use PUT. Then try to put this in your update function

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($input);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

See, if you are getting values. If you are getting then store the update result into a variable like:

$response = Participant::where('idparticipant', '=', $id)->update($input);

then again print this: (To find if there is any validation error)

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response->errors());
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```